Is it Possible to Force a SQL Pulled String Displayed in FPDF to have Different Sizing to Another String in the Same Double Quotes/Cell?
Context
This project is for an invoice application that generates a pdf from a button click. Its plain and simple, approched with the MVP concept. Over time, I did add a few details but they do not interfere with the PDF generation.
My Tool Belt
The tools I've used for R&D are:

M1 with Sonoma 14.3.1,
Visual Studio Code Version: 1.89.1 (Universal),
Latest PHP version (8.2),
FPDF (1.86),
Latest MySQL (8.X),
Brave, FireFox and Safari (Latest Version),
Perplexity AI (GPT 3.5)

Problem
In the latest FPDF version, I want to change the words thats coming from a MySQL database to be bigger in size AND displayed in the same CELL. This means displaying the following:
<?php
  include('PATH/TO/FPDF');

  class PDF extends FPDF 
  {
    function Info($data) {
      $this->Cell(190, 5, "NAME:       " . $data['name'], "B", 0, "L");
    }
  }
?>

where the name column (from MySQL), should be bigger in font size than "NAME:      " in the output.
What I Tried
I've used the following methods (from FPDF), with no success:

MultiCell
SetFont
GetY
GetX
Ln
SetFontSize
SetX
SetY
SetXY
Write

Yes, I did look on StackOverFlow and Googled it, and as similar as the titles are to solving my problem, they do not provide the actual solution. I also verfied just now if there are any answers out there to answer my question as my last chance. There are none :( . I need to make the data from MySQL bigger like in the PDF from Acrobat where you're filling out a form. Imagine filling out a PDF form for the goverment or scholarships, they make the user inputs bigger that the hard-coded string.
The mentioned methods used were also the ones I've implemented to solve this problem. I've used many more methods that aren't mentioned, and they obviously lead to nowhere.
What I Got
I am currently stuck on the Cell method and from researching article, youtube videos and blog posts, have gotten no where near to my goal.
Quick Review
Heres the documentation:

FPDF Official Documentation


A Cell() has a single style.

Can you please explain what you mean by that? If you're referring to the "B" and "L" letters being used, yes in a way a Cell does have styling, but it does not have independent font size styling of a single string as of what I know. That is my problem and why I want to check if it's true. "B" is for a bottom border and "L" is for aligning the text to the left side of the Cell. Similar in Word, Excel and PowerPoint. OR, are you telling me no to answer my question?
